# Translating regex match groups

Tags: python, regex

I need to match *name objects* according to pdf file specification. However, names may contain hexadecimal digits (preceded by #) to specify *special* characters. I would like to translate these matches to corresponding characters. Is there a clever way to do it without re-parsing the match string?

```
import re

Name = re.compile(r'''
    (/                                        # Literal "/"
        (?:                                   #
            (?:\#[A-Fa-f0-9]{2})              # Hex numbers
            |                                 # 
            [^\x00-\x20 \x23 \x2f \x7e-\xff]  # Other
        )+                                    #
    )                                         #
    ''', re.VERBOSE)

#  some examples

names = """
    The following are examples of valid literal names:

    Raw string                       Translation

    1.  /Adobe#20Green            -> "Adobe Green"
    2.  /PANTONE#205757#20CV      -> "PANTONE 5757 CV"
    3.  /paired#28#29parentheses  -> "paired( )parentheses"
    4.  /The_Key_of_F#23_Minor    -> "The_Key_of_F#_Minor"
    5.  /A#42                     -> "AB"
    6.  /Name1
    7.  /ASomewhatLongerName
    8.  /A;Name_With-Various***Characters?
    9.  /1.2
    10. /$$
    11. /@pattern
    12. /.notdef
    """
```

Comment: You want to replace this in the input string? Or you want to list matching names with the escape sequences unescaped?

Comment: Can you use `re.sub`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- `list matching names with the escape sequences unescaped`

Comment: @Jack -- Yes, I can use `re.sub` on the match, but I was wondering if there was a more "clever" way...

Comment: Having matching and conversion in two distinct steps has its advantages imo ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `finditer()` with a wrapper generator:

```
import re
from functools import partial

def _hexrepl(match):
    return chr(int(match.group(1), 16))
unescape = partial(re.compile(r'#([0-9A-F]{2})').sub, _hexrepl)

def pdfnames(inputtext):
    for match in Name.finditer(inputtext):
        yield unescape(match.group(0))
```

Demo:

```
>>> for name in pdfnames(names):
...     print name
... 
/Adobe Green
/PANTONE 5757 CV
/paired()parentheses
/The_Key_of_F#_Minor
/AB
/Name1
/ASomewhatLongerName
/A;Name_With-Various***Characters?
/1.2
/$$
/@pattern
/.notdef
```

There is no more clever way that *I* know of; the `re` engine cannot otherwise combine substitution and matching.

Comment: Thanks, then `re.sub` it is :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `re.sub`.

You can use this with a function to match hex '#[0-9A-F]{2}' numbers and translate these using a function.

E.g.

```
def hexrepl(m):
    return chr(int(m.group(0)[1:3],16))

re.sub(r'#[0-9A-F]{2}', hexrepl, '/Adobe#20Green')
```

Will return '/Adobe Green'

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then he should also have the wits to mention that in the question and why it doesn't work :)

Comment: @Jack: I am asking for clarification; what he wants is not clear.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Yes, maybe root is looking for a "one pass regular expression".

Comment: Sorry, about the confusion... I actually implement something similar to yours and Martijn's, but thought that there may be some better way. Anyway +1.